# Traversable lazy filter

Tags: scala

I was recently surprised by the implementation of `Traversable`'s `filter` method. I was expecting the filter to be lazy but instead it seems to create a new physical collection.

This leads to problems when the traversable is used like

```
trav.filter(/*...*/).take(10)
```

If the traversable is computed on the fly, unnecessary computation takes place, because I only need the first 10 elements the computation generates which satisfy the condition. The current implementation seems to evaluate the whole computation. To help with this I created an implicit class with lazyFilter method:

```
implicit class TravLazyFilter[T](underlying: Traversable[T]) {
    def lazyFilter(cond: T => Boolean) = new Traversable[T] {
        def foreach[U](func: T => U) = {
            underlying.foreach { x =>
                if (cond(x))
                    func(x)
                else {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now to the questions:

- Is my assumption about the `Traversable` `filter` method correct?
- Am I misusing `Traversable` when I use it to hide a computation?
- Is the `lazyFilter` method above correct?
- Is there a built in way to do what `lazyFilter` does? (I tried `view`, but it doesn't seem to help)

Comment: What do you mean on `(I tried view, but it doesn't seem to help)`? It should work.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that `trav.view.filter(cond).take(10)` seems to also evaluate the whole computation

Comment: What do you mean in "seems"? Please provide code sample for `view` with creation of `Traversable` to show problems with `view`.

Comment: also i think you need a "force" at the end?

Comment: Ok, looks I'm just wasting your time, when I did a small example the view works as expected. I will have to look at what I am doing wrong in my real case. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: Now that I think back at it the problem is that the filter condition matches exactly the amount of elements that i `take`. The implementation of `TraversableView` `take` method needs one more, which it does not find. That means it traverses the whole traversable.